# Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: Valid schemes are http or https

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using `-[NSURLSessionBackgroundFetch start]` method for background fetch as a result of push notification in my app. This method completely works fine and my app is successfully uploaded on store. But one of our user got the following crash:

Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: (null). Valid schemes are http or https

```
-[NSURLSessionBackgroundFetch start]
```

I am unable to get any solution, why this crash occured in production mode and not in development.Also, only one of our user got this crash.

Comment: you can use testflight sdk for getting more detail about crash

Comment: We used testflight sdk that notified the crash in production. But why this occurred not able to understand as it works for others also in development.

Comment: Does the app fetch from any urls that it gets from the server?  If it were to fetch a nil url and pass it to a request, somewhere down in the depths someone would end up with a null scheme and be unhappy about it.

Comment: What is `NSURLSessionBackgroundFetch`? A class? It doesn't look like part of [any API](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=NSURLSessionBackgroundFetch&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#nfpr=1&q=NSURLSessionBackgroundFetch&rls=en).